Solana Client.send_transaction() not returning response
I am trying to work with Solana in Python and I am trying to send an SPL token.
The transaction successfully sends & I can see logger logging the HTTP request, however, I can't get the response with the signature ID.
This is my code:
transfer_spl_token:
    # Initialize Solana client
    client = Client(endpoint=SOLANA_ENDPOINT, commitment="processed")

    # Create transaction
    transaction = Transaction()

    # Get the associated token account address for the destination
    associated_token_address = get_associated_token_address(dest_pubkey, mint_pubkey)
    
    # Get our associated token account address for the source
    source_associated_token_address = get_associated_token_address(source_pubkey, mint_pubkey)
    
    logger.info(f"Source Associated Token Address: {source_associated_token_address}")
    logger.info(f"Destination Associated Token Address: {associated_token_address}")

    # Check if the associated token account exists
    response = client.get_account_info(associated_token_address)
    if response.value is None:
        # Create associated token account instruction if it doesn't exist
        create_ata_instruction = create_associated_token_account(
            payer=source_pubkey,
            owner=dest_pubkey,
            mint=mint_pubkey
        )
        transaction.add(create_ata_instruction)

    # Convert amount to smallest units
    transfer_amount = int(amount * (10 ** decimals))
    logger.info(f"Transfer amount in smallest units: {transfer_amount}")

    # Add the token transfer instruction
    transaction.add(
        transfer_checked(
            TransferCheckedParams(
                program_id=TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
                source=source_associated_token_address,
                mint=mint_pubkey,
                dest=associated_token_address,
                owner=source_keypair.pubkey(),
                amount=transfer_amount,
                decimals=decimals
            )
        )
    )
    
    # Send transaction
    response = client.send_transaction(transaction, source_keypair, opts=TxOpts(skip_confirmation=False, preflight_commitment="processed"))
    logger.info(response)

I'm calling this function here:
async def confirm_buy:
    # Transfer SPL token
    signature = transfer_spl_token(deposit_address, user_address, token_amount, privkey, mint_address)
    logger.info(signature)

This is what I see in my logger:
- httpx - INFO - HTTP Request: POST https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com "HTTP/1.1 200 OK"
- solanaweb3.rpc.httprpc.HTTPClient - INFO - Transaction sent to https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com. Signature noZ2x.....AHwaX:
- httpx - INFO - HTTP Request: POST https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com "HTTP/1.1 200 OK"
- httpx - INFO - HTTP Request: POST https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com "HTTP/1.1 200 OK"
- httpx - INFO - HTTP Request: POST https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com "HTTP/1.1 200 OK"
- httpx - INFO - HTTP Request: POST https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com "HTTP/1.1 200 OK"
- httpx - INFO - HTTP Request: POST https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com "HTTP/1.1 200 OK"
- httpx - INFO - HTTP Request: POST https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com "HTTP/1.1 200 OK"
- httpx - INFO - HTTP Request: POST https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com "HTTP/1.1 200 OK"
- httpx - INFO - HTTP Request: POST https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com "HTTP/1.1 200 OK"
- httpx - INFO - HTTP Request: POST https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com "HTTP/1.1 200 OK"
- httpx - INFO - HTTP Request: POST https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com "HTTP/1.1 200 OK"
- httpx - INFO - HTTP Request: POST https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com "HTTP/1.1 429 Too Many Requests"

I am new to Solana programming and not too sure what's going on. Do I need to sign the transaction before sending it (so I have the txn ID already)?
I tried changing the commitment/pre-flight commitment.
I tried making the function async
I can't get the response from send_transaction()
I was expecting to get signature

You have to rate limit, then also sign the transaction

@TowsifAhamedLabib Thanks. Should I sign the transaction before sending it?

Also, do you think you can give me some guidance on how to rate limit the requests?

Rate Limiting: The function is decorated with sleep_and_retry and limits decorators to handle rate limits.
Async/Await: The function and all API calls are converted to asynchronous, improving efficiency and response time.
Transaction Signing: Ensured that the transaction is properly constructed and signed before being sent.
Error Handling: Implement proper error handling around network calls to manage exceptions and API limits.
import asyncio
from ratelimit import limits, sleep_and_retry

# Constants for rate limiting
CALLS = 10
PERIOD = 60

@sleep_and_retry
@limits(calls=CALLS, period=PERIOD)
async def transfer_spl_token(client, source_keypair, source_pubkey, dest_pubkey, mint_pubkey, amount, decimals):
    # Create transaction
    transaction = Transaction()

    # Get the associated token account addresses
    source_associated_token_address = await get_associated_token_address(source_pubkey, mint_pubkey)
    associated_token_address = await get_associated_token_address(dest_pubkey, mint_pubkey)

    logger.info(f"Source Associated Token Address: {source_associated_token_address}")
    logger.info(f"Destination Associated Token Address: {associated_token_address}")

    # Check if the destination account exists
    response = await client.get_account_info(associated_token_address)
    if response['result']['value'] is None:
        create_ata_instruction = create_associated_token_account(
            payer=source_pubkey,
            owner=dest_pubkey,
            mint=mint_pubkey
        )
        transaction.add(create_ata_instruction)

    # Convert amount to smallest units and add the token transfer instruction
    transfer_amount = int(amount * (10 ** decimals))
    logger.info(f"Transfer amount in smallest units: {transfer_amount}")

    transfer_instruction = transfer_checked(
        TransferCheckedParams(
            program_id=TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
            source=source_associated_token_address,
            mint=mint_pubkey,
            dest=associated_token_address,
            owner=source_keypair.public_key(),
            amount=transfer_amount,
            decimals=decimals
        )
    )
    transaction.add(transfer_instruction)

    # Sign and send the transaction
    response = await client.send_transaction(transaction, source_keypair, opts=TxOpts(skip_confirmation=False, preflight_commitment="processed"))
    logger.info(f"Transaction response: {response}")
    return response

# Usage example
async def main():
    client = Client(endpoint=SOLANA_ENDPOINT, commitment="processed")
    source_keypair = load_keypair()  # Assuming a function to load your keypair
    source_pubkey = source_keypair.public_key()
    dest_pubkey = 'Destination public key here'
    mint_pubkey = 'Mint public key here'
    amount = 1.0
    decimals = 9

    response = await transfer_spl_token(client, source_keypair, source_pubkey, dest_pubkey, mint_pubkey, amount, decimals)
    logger.info(f"Final transaction signature: {response}")

# Run the async main function
if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())

Let me know, if this guideline works, or need to improve upon it

References: https://michaelhly.com/solana-py/ https://solana.com/docs/core/transactions

Hi, thanks for your response. I am still getting the same behavior as before.

Is the asyncio.run() part needed? I cannot run my function like that, because I am working with a Telegram Bot

Not strictly needed, but you can do async calls with tg bot i/o operations, complex but possible
